# How do we share compilation settings between project members in VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I want to set up some settings for building Unreal Engine 4 in Visual Studio 2017, and then share them so all programmers on the project have the same build environment.

For example treating warnings as errors, using more strict compilation settings.

However it's very difficult to find where these settings are stored, and how they can be shared in a simple file in a project directory. I've searched for the better part of an hour and not found anything clear.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Aren't those saved in the project settings? Then if the project is shared with a source-control system (which you *really* should have) then they will all get the same (checked-in) settings.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are stored in the project files (*.vcxproj) which you should include in your CVS (e.g. Git).

The files are really xml documents so you can even see where the settings are stored in the file if you make a change and look at the file diff.